# change TabView indicator color SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image]

Is there a way to change the tabView Indicator color in swiftUI ?

This is my code

```
struct OnBoarding: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(0 ..< 3) { item in
                VStack {
                    Image("discover")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                }
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: Color ?))   
    }
}

struct OnBoarding_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OnBoarding()
    }
}
```

I tried `tabViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: Color ?))`, but can't get around with it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

you need to use UIkit

```
 init() {
    UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .red
    UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    }
```

Comment: Where should put this init? & is it affects on other paginate styles in the app?

Comment: This affects all screens in the app. If you want to change it on only one view then you should put these lines in onAppear and then use onDisappear to undo the change when you leave the view. (Using nil as the value for both seems to reset them to the defaults)

Answer (score 26):

Basically you need to set the global variable when your view appears. One way to do it is as follows:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct OnboardingView: View {
  
  var pages: [Page]
  
  var body: some View {
  
    TabView {
      ForEach(pages) { page in
        // Your component view
      }
    }
    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    .onAppear {
      setupAppearance()
    }
  }
  
  func setupAppearance() {
    UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .black
    UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work now but @Achraf's version which in init() works. I don't know why...

Comment: This sets appearance globally.

Answer (score 6):

> First create a subview like:

```
struct SliderTabView: View {
init() {
          UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .red
          UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
       }
var body: some View {
    TabView{
        ForEach(players){ player in
            //Slider content here ...
        }
    }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
}
```

> Call the subview from main view like:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
          var body: some View {
                                 SliderTabView()
                              }
                             }
```

the output look like of me:
[image]

Comment: How did you get the indicator dots below the content?

Comment: Give enough space for SliderTabView()

Answer (score 5):

If you are using SwiftUI from UIKit there's a more delicate way to update UIPageControl appearance.

```swift
// SwiftUI with with UIPageControl
struct MyView: View { ... }
```

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

final class MyViewContainerController: UIHostingController<MyView> {
    init() {
        let view = MyView()
        super.init(rootView: view)
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let containerTypes = [MyViewContainerController.self]
        let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: containerTypes)
        appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .systemBlue
        appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = .systemIndigo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply don't want to mess with UIKit on SwiftUI, or you need to give the color after init:

**Create your own! and have total style control**

[image]

```
@State private var tabSelection = 0

var body: some View {
 ZStack(alignment:.bottom){
    TabView(selection: $tabSelection.animation()){
                                Text("Slide 1")
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .tag(0)
                                Text("Slide 2")
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .tag(1)
                                Text("Slide 3")
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .tag(2)
                            }
                            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
     HStack(spacing: 6){
              ForEach(0..<3) { i in
                  Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                      .font(.system(size: 9))
                      .foregroundStyle(tabSelection == i ? .black : .gray)
               }
     }
                            .padding(.bottom)
 }
}
```