# How to change default TabView Navigator

Tags: xcode, swiftui

[Image of default navigator with my own navigator (purple dots) under it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I50uv.png)

Is there any way I can change the color of the translucent navigator dots?

My code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var selection = 0
var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(0..<5){i in
                if(i == 0) {
                    FirstPageView()
                } else if (i==1) {
                    SecondPageView()
                } else if i==2 {
                    ThirdPageView()
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    
}
```

}

Thank you!!

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68143240/tabview-dot-index-color-does-not-change

Comment: Achraf gives you the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864221/change-tabview-indicator-swiftui